# Activiti :call the end event of the file bpmn (error case )

Tags: java, activiti

When I start my workflow I insert data in my table x which has a column "error".

Before inserting, I make some tests and there are cases that generate errors. In this case I value the "error" column, and I have to stop the process in activiti side which means to call the end of the circuit otherwise I will have the column "error" valued and activiti side the circuit is in progress.

I don't know how to inform activiti that i have an error and i want to call the end event

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the potion of the process you want to be able to exit out of immediately in either a subprocess or called activity and add a boundary error event to the sub-process/called activity.
When you want to exit, simply throw an BPMNError from either a listener, delegate or script task.

Te boundary event will catch the exception and route you wherever you want, in this case to the end.